# How to avoid "No matching client found for package name" for google-services.json?

Tags: android

I am using `google-services.json` file in my app. There is a field in this file

```
...
"client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "my_id",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "my_package_name"
        }
      },
...
```

Then in order to distinguish between `release` and `debug` I added this line in my `.gradle` file

```
debug {
            ...
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
```

And then I get an error in `debug` build that my package name in `google-services.json` not the same with my package name. And I understand this issue, because in `google-services.json` package name is `my_package_name`, but after I added that line in my `.gradle` file my package name in debug build is `my_package_name.debug` it is not the same.

So, it is means that now I need every time when I switch between `release` and `debug` I need go to `google-services.json` and change it as well.

I almost sure that here should be solution, question is - how to do it correctly? In order to avoid open `google-services.json` every time when I switch build variant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add another app with `.debug` suffix to your Firebase project.

So your new `google-services.json` file will contain both these apps like this:

```
  "client_info": {
    "mobilesdk_app_id": "...",
    "android_client_info": {
      "package_name": "com.company.project.debug"
    }
  },

  "client_info": {
    "mobilesdk_app_id": "...",
    "android_client_info": {
      "package_name": "com.company.project"
    }
  }
```

Reference: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/organizing-your-firebase-enabled-android-app-builds.html

Answer (score 1):

`google-services.json` file allows several entries for different app flavours that you have. Just go into the `Firebase Console` and add the new app, set its name to `my_package_name.debug`. I have about 6-7 different package names for the same app, it just adds another entry in your generated `json`.